# extjs 4 invalid target element for this operation

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I don't understand why In Firefox everything works properly, but in IE 7 I get the following error :

Message: Invalid target element for this operation.
Line: 6455
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://extdev/gdevapp/extjs/ext-all-debug.js

here is my code bellow. the error happens in the ligne of mainapp.add statment (THANKS IN ADAVANCE):

```
    doConnect:function(btn){

    var winlogin=btn.up('window');
    var statusbarlogin=winlogin.down('statusbar');
    var myloginform=winlogin.down('form');   


     if (myloginform.getForm().isValid()) {
        statusbarlogin.showBusy();
        //submit form to login  

        myloginform.submit({
           url    :'/gdev/ngsecure.glogin',
           method :'POST',
           scope  :this,
           success :function(form,action){
                     var msgtxt=action.result.data.msgtxt;

                     devglob.userid=action.result.data.userid;
                     devglob.connid=action.result.data.connid;
                     devglob.userfullname=action.result.data.userfullname;
                     devglob.userfunction=action.result.data.userfunction;

                     statusbarlogin.setText(msgtxt+'\/ID Utilisateur : '+devglob.userid);

                     //BuildApplication 

                     var mainapp=Ext.getCmp('mainapp');
                     var appview=Ext.getCmp('appview');

                     if (!appview) {                        
                        //load and render the main application                      

                        mainapp.removeAll();                        
                        mainapp.add(Ext.widget('appview'));                     
                        mainapp.doLayout();

                        //Build a toolbar items
                        var mytoolbar=Ext.getCmp('toolbarapp');        
                        mytoolbar.loadItems(devglob.userid);
                     };

                     //close the login window
                     winlogin.close();
                   },
           failure:function(form,action){
                   var msgtxt=action.result.data.msgtxt;
                   Ext.MessageBox.alert('Erreur',msgtxt);
                  }         
        });      
     }
     else {



     }


     //get result ajax


   }
```

Comment: Could not guess. It could be the problem in your `appview` class. Perhaps you can share appview class too?

Comment: Yes my friend, I found the problem comming from my class appview. The problem is : I used xtype:'panel' with autoEl:{tag:'img',...}. When I changed xtype to 'box', everything works properly. So thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using a container's `insert()` method when programatically adding ComboBoxes to a panel with the form layout, and following your comment on your question I changed the layout from

```
layout: 'form',
```

to

```
layout: 'vbox',
```

The IE issue was then fixed

```
Ext.getCmp('col-1').insert(0, portlet);
```